# Unable to find partition for path '/sdcard' in TWRP

Tags: rooting, root-access, internal-storage, twrp, 7.1-nougat

I have been trying to root my Nexus 5x running Android 7.1.2 (N2G47F)

So put SuperSU.zip file to install it from TWRP.

I executed following command -
*fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.0.2-0-bullhead.img*

But when I get into TWRP I can not find SU file becouse TWRP can not find nexus build in card.

In log console I am getting following error.

**Unable to find partition for path '/sdcard'**

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like encryption. Try using the latest version [here](https://dl.twrp.me/bullhead/).

Comment: nice. Newere version unlike older asked me for password. I was able to root my phone thank you.

Comment: I'm moving that to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like encryption is blocking the recovery from accessing the internal storage. Try using the latest version [here](https://dl.twrp.me/bullhead/).